# Send email out when a select query returns a certain value

Tags: shell, command-line

I want to send an email out after a select query returns a certain value.

I currently pipe it to a text file just to give me some display.

```
echo "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE status = -20;" | mysql -u user -pXXX -h 
          servername --database=chosenDB >> /var/log/DBcheck.txt
```

now when the value returns to "-20" or whatever number I choose how would I go about creating an email alert to send when it turns true.  Using it as a monitoring tool.  The server I am running already is set up with postfix, which is confirmed working.

any info would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: you'll improve your chances of good answers by adding a tag for the shell you are using. tag Shell is usually used by windows people. Indicate bash, ksh, csh, or ??? Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Here comes the Sun | mail -s Subject <email-address>
```

should send the email. You need to put this inside the correct if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns a single line of output, perhaps something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

case `echo "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE status = -20;" |
    mysql -u user -pXXX -h servername --database=chosenDB` in
  -20) echo It is minus twenty | /usr/lib/sendmail -oi you@example.com ;;
esac
```

More usefully, put the output in a temp file, and erase it if it's uninteresting.

```
#!/bin/sh

t=`mktemp -t muesliXXXXXXX`  # Not entirely portable -- google this bit
trap 'rm -f $t' 0
trap 'exit 127' 1 2 3 5 15

mysql -u user -pXXX -h servername --database=chosenDB <<'____HERE' >$t
    SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE status = -20;
____HERE

if grep -qw '-20' $t; then
  ( cat <<'____HERE'; cat $t) | /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t
From: Friendly Cron Job <root@example.com>
To: you <you@example.com>
Subject: It is Minus Twenty

____HERE
fi
```

Some shells / some cats will allow you to use a here document and a named file at the same time, avoiding the Useless Use of Cat.

```
cat - $t <<'____HERE' | /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t
```

But I am afraid this is not entirely portable.

The `grep` is just to give you an idea; replace it with something less ad hoc, perhaps actually parsing the output file and performing complex logic on the result of the parse.